# libgdx - Smoothing edges of Texture on lower resolution devices

Tags: android, libgdx

1. ver: 128 x 128 circle sprite with Linear, Linear filter. It looks fine on a Full HD resolution, but on lower resolution I can see alot of the pixels. + on some devices top and right pixels are missing
2. ver: So I made a 127x127 circle on a 128x128 dimension png. + I also manually made around the edge a 2pixel transperancy, that goes from 100% transparent to 0, so it would look smooth in game. On Full HD still looks fine, but now on smaller screens the edge looks blurry. And still top and right are missing pixels, but a little less.

1 - What is causing the missing pixels? And so randomly across devices. Somewhere missing, somewhere not, if I would make a 125x125 circle, I would get all the pixels, but what is the problem?

2 - How do you go about making for all the phones. Although 2nd version still looks better, but it seems like it is blurry around the edges.

Comment: Are you using [mipmapping](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/MIP_Mapping) ? It should prevent smaller version of you texture to be this way distorted.

Comment: Yep, I set the filter to MipMapLinearLinear, Linear, which should be the best, and they are still so disorted... Still missing few pixels. Only way to get rid of that is to use a a few transperent pixels around the texture...